# Target parameter count exception on delegate Sub

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I have the following code to write some text from different functions and subs but that has been working ok but now I'm getting the target parameter count exception when I call the delegate from SerialPort DataReceived event.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, Any ideas?

```
Delegate Sub PrintSmsLogDelegate(ByVal NewText As String, ByVal NewLine As Boolean)

Protected Friend Sub PrintSmsLog(ByVal NewText As String, Optional ByVal NewLine As Boolean = True)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim Txt As New PrintSmsLogDelegate(AddressOf PrintSmsLog)
        'Me.Invoke(Txt, NewText)'This fail too
        Me.Invoke(Txt, New Object() {NewText}) '<--- TargetParameterCountException
    Else
        '...       
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SmsSerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SmsSerialPort.DataReceived

    '...   code to receive data and save it in "Lines" variable
    Dim Lines as String

    Me.PrintSmsLog(Lines, False)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `PrintSmsLogDelegate` delegate declaration contains 2 required parameter.
So you have to provide the 2nd parameter as well.

The method signature for `Invoke` method is this:
`Function Control.Invoke(method As [Delegate], ParamArray args As Object()) As Object`

So you should call your `PrintSmsLogDelegate` delegate instance (which is `Txt`) with two parameters even if the `PrintSmsLog` method does not require the 2nd parameter.

```
Me.Invoke(Txt, NewText, True)
```

You cannot call the `Invoke` method with a single array parameter. Due to `ParamArray` keyword an array will be automatically created of the multiple parameter you specify.